# How to get firebase UID in cloud function when user uninstalls the app?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-analytics

I want to detect app uninstall events through the firebase analytic trigger function. Firebase function is shown below

```
   exports.appUninstall = functions.analytics.event('app_remove').onLog(event => {
    
     const user = event.user;    
     const uid = user.userId; 

     var time = Date.now();      
     var orderKey = 9999999999999 - Date.now();  
         
     var updateMap = {};
     
     updateMap["time"] = time;
     updateMap["orderKey"] = orderKey;
     updateMap["uid"] = uid;
                          
     updateMap['/Uninstalls/'+ uid] = updateMap;
                           
     return admin.database().ref().update(updateMap);
      
     
});
```

But it shows the following error. - undefined in property 'uid'

```
Error: Reference.update failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'uid'
at validateFirebaseData (/workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1481:15)
at /workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1601:9
at each (/workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:554:13)
at validateFirebaseMergeDataArg (/workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1599:5)
at Reference.update (/workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:13838:9)
at exports.appUninstall.functions.analytics.event.onLog.event (/workspace/index.js:1012:36)
at cloudFunction (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:134:23)
at Promise.resolve.then (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:199:28)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

I know I am doing something wrong. How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaking you need to set the user ID by using the `setUserId` API. See the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/userid?hl=en) for more details on how to do that for each platform (Android, iOS, ...). Then, you will be able to get it in your Cloud Function, with the code of your question.